# How do I cherry-pick an unmerged commit from github?

Tags: git, github

I want to cherry-pick this patch: https://github.com/gioele/vim-autoswap/pull/17/commits/b9f49977bac269be90807dc27c9931517c84ff15

I have the repository cloned and tried:

`git cherry-pick b9f49977bac269be90807dc27c9931517c84ff15`

Got:

`fatal: bad object b9f49977bac269be90807dc27c9931517c84ff15`

Comment: You should `fetch` the commit first.

Comment: OK, thanks. Googling with fetch helped me find the solution.

Answer (score -1):

OK, here is the solution, starting from a cloned github repo:

1) set upstream repo (skip this step if already set)

`git remote add upstream https://github.com/<gh_huser>/<gh_repo_name>.git`

2) Find the "pull request" number. In the case of the original post, it is "17". Use it in the next step.

3) Fetch the pull request

`git fetch upstream pull/<pull_request_number>/head:<new_branch_name>`